# How do i solve the following sql syntax error

Tags: python, mysql, syntax-error, bind-variables

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':Username, :passw, :addrss, :DOB, :emil, :ag)' at line 1

THE CODE:

```
def submit():
    
    my_cursor = mydb.cursor()

    #INSERT INTO TABLE

    my_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO madhav VALUES (:Username, :passw, :addrss, :DOB, :emil, :ag)",
        {
            'Username': Username.get(),
            'passw'   : passw.get(),
            'addrss'  : addrss.get(),
            'DOB'     : DOB.get(),
            'emil'    : emil.get(),
            'ag'      : ag.get()
        })


    mydb.commit()
    mydb.close()


    # Clear The Text Boxes
    Username.delete(0,END)
    passw.delete(0,END)
    addrss.delete(0,END)
    DOB.delete(0,END)
    emil.delete(0,END)
    ag.delete(0,END)
```

The above function is used to insert values into a database using a GUI

Comment: show the "CREATE TABLE" SQL and explain what is the data type that is returned from `Username.get()` etc.

Comment: ...as an aside, why are you leaving letters out? `passw` is no easier to type than `password`, and the latter is _much_ clearer. Ditto `emil` vs `email`. In fact, the full words are probably _easier_ to type since they are real words that you may have muscle memory for. Clarity is important. Saving a byte here or there in your source code provide no benefits whatsoever.

Comment: my_cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE madhav (name VARCHAR(255), password VARCHAR(255), address VARCHAR(255), DT DATE , email VARCHAR(255), age INTEGER(10), user_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT Primary key)") this is the create table sql

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you use named parameters in mydb. The correct syntax for such a parameter is `%(name)s`. So, in your case:

```py
my_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO madhav VALUES (%(Username)s, %(passw)s, %(addrss)s, %(DOB)s, %(emil)s, %(ag)s)",
    {
        'Username': Username.get(),
        'passw'   : passw.get(),
        'addrss'  : addrss.get(),
        'DOB'     : DOB.get(),
        'emil'    : emil.get(),
        'ag'      : ag.get()
    })
```

Comment: thank you for the code but another error popped up saying 
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 .........im pretty new to this so sorry if the error/doubt is stupid

Comment: @tyzion I missed the closing `)` at the end of the `values` clause, my apologies. Edited and fixed.

Comment: @Mureinik Why the `%` and the `s` ..If you could add that in the answer, it would help a lot passers-by like me.. Thanks.

Comment: @AbhishekRai As I noted, that's the syntax mydb uses for named parameters. Not quite sure how I can clarify this further...

Comment: @Mureinik Well, This comment of yours will help passers-by. :)

Answer (score 0):

The values take type of variable, like string, integar etc.
So you code will become

stmt= (
"INSERT INTO madhav (Username, passw, addrss, DOB, emil, ag) "
"VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
)

Because all fielda are string type so there is %s otherwise for integar it will be %i
Next you can bound this stmt with data to execute.

data = (Username.get(), passw.get(), addrss.get(), DOB.get(),emil.get(),ag.get())
my_cursor.execute(stmt, data)

See these docs for more info
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html